# Show/Hide on click with Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have created a basic show/hide functionality with Angular but I feel like there has to be a more elegant solution.

Here is a plnkr with my current code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8NfhTL25Y8gOoGMXiP2?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <label>
      <input class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" (click)='question1()'>
      <div class="pvq-create-label">
        <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh?</p>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label [@hideShow]='state1'>Answer
      <input type="textbox" name="">
    </label>
  </div>
```

Logic:

```
  state1: string = 'inactive';
  state2: string = 'inactive';

  question1() {
    this.state1 = (this.state1 === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
  }

  question2() {
    this.state2 = (this.state2 === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
  }
```

Comment: Here's an alternative using forms: http://plnkr.co/edit/pemDTePMm8hY1lJ3Nwfi?p=preview. I don't know much about animations, but what I fear will be the problem is that the answer text boxes are still in the DOM when hidden, so validators still apply, even when they're invisible.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Angular, is your way the best practice in terms of what I'd like to achieve? Is this what you would do if you were trying to achieve the same result but starting from scratch?

Comment: I don't know animations well enough to answer that. But surely you need to know what the values of the checkboxes and the input fields are, so you'd need a form and binding.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-engineering by using the `animations` DSL for such a simple animation. If you only need to modify the opacity, you might as well use `css` and toggle classes.

Example `component.ts`:

```
class MyComponent {

    showButtons: any = {
        q1: false,
        q2: false
    }

    toggleButton(button: string): void {
        this.showButtons[button] = !this.showButtons[button]
    }
}
```

*component.html*

```
<input type="text" [class.show]="showButtons.q1" placeholder="Answer 1">
<button (click)="toggleButton('q1')">Show question 1</button>

<input type="text" [class.show]="showButtons.q2" placeholder="Answer 2">
<button (click)="toggleButton('q2')">Show question 2</button>
```

Now you toggle the `show` class in each of those inputs. You can create the simple animation in `css` instead of using animations.

Comment: So at what point would you start using Angular's animations properties?

I don't want to start doing some animations in through CSS and then some through Angular.

Comment: @Dachan Well, you could use Angular's animations DSL anytime you want and ditch css animations entirely. I personally think that some basic animations take way too many lines of coding with Angular's `animations` DSL whereas it would only take a few with css. If you don't like to do some with Angular and some with css, go with full `animations` DSL.